# Looking to create a filter based on a rating/score for archiving purposes for a podcast

Tags: google-sheets

I've messed around in the custom formula and using what I've dug up on youtube and stackoverflow to no avail. I'm trying to archive reviews for a site and am making a filter. I already have filters set for Anime Title and Reviewers. I want to make a new filter (**on the same sheet like the other filters**) that will be based on score/ratings from best to worst and vice versa. "Download Now" is the best (a 5), "Pie" is almost perfect (a 4), "Crackers" is really good (a 3), "Netflix" is ok (a 2), and "Burn it" is the worst rating (a 1).
Looking for any and all help to set this up. Please and thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you thought of using the filters from sheets on the column? Go to Data -> Create filter. Also, can you share more details on how do you need this filter?

Comment: I was looking to sort using the filter and rate it from best to worst. Does that help?

Comment: Have you tried to do it? Can you update on your progress?

Comment: There is no update as there hasn't been any assistance, suggestions or further questions. I'm still waiting on my end.

Comment: Have you tried using the filters from spreadsheets? The ones mentioned on the first comment?

Comment: I've messed around in the custom formula and using what I've dug up on youtube and stackoverflow to no avail. I'm trying to archive reviews for a site and am making a filter. I already have filters set for Anime Title and Reviewers. I want to make a new filter (on the same sheet like the other filters) that will be based on score/ratings from best to worst and vice versa.
Right in the OP. I've tried and have had no luck. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly, what I was mentioning were the filters without any functions (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) those ones, then you can filter for a specific column and change the order every time

Comment: Never mind. Another forum was able to assist me. Posting the answer here.

Comment: I understand that you are using Filter for sorting purposes.

Anime - A-Z
Reviewer - A-Z
Episode - A-Z
Score - Custom Sort

You want to filter (sort) the "Score" in a custom way. As far as I know, "Filter by condition" is only for filtering out unwanted rows, not for sorting. So, you should use a helper column.
See the tab "pkv test"
In cell E2, I have entered the below formula.

={"Score Helper";ArrayFormula(ifna(match($C$3:$C,{"Download Now","Pi","Crackers","Crackers/Download Now","Netflix","Netflix/Crackers","Burn It","Burn It/Netflix","NA"},0)))}

Now View "By Score Helper"

Answer (score 0):

Solution shared by the user on the last comment:

I understand that you are using Filter for sorting purposes.

Anime - A-Z Reviewer - A-Z Episode - A-Z Score - Custom Sort You want to filter (sort) the "Score" in a custom way.

As far as I know, "Filter by condition" is only for filtering out unwanted rows, not for sorting. So, you should use a helper column.

See the tab "pkv test" In cell E2, I have entered the below formula.

`={"Score Helper";ArrayFormula(ifna(match($C$3:$C,{"Download Now","Pi","Crackers","Crackers/Download Now","Netflix","Netflix/Crackers","Burn It","Burn It/Netflix","NA"},0)))}`

Now View "By Score Helper"